# Applying student loan proceeds toward tuition?

Tags: canada, student-loan, tuition

Background:

I have been granted a student loan of a few thousand Canadian dollars and accepted into full-time, first-year, first-semester university. I have received a few scholarships which covers most of my tuition fees. Only a few hundred dollars from the student loan went to pay my tuition. The remaining money is currently in my bank account.

Question:

What steps do I need to take to have the remaining money go into my second-semester tuition?

Comment: If the money's in your bank account, you just use it to pay the tuition bill...or the phone bill...or to buy groceries.

Comment: You should save that money as best you can and then use it to pay the future tuition bill when it comes.  Even if the university allows you to prepay for next semester, I would recommend against it.  You never know what will happen, and if you are not able to attend that semester you will still be on the hook for the loan.

Answer (score 1):

Your university should have a finance department which can help with payments. Speak with them and tell them you have interest in paying for at least part of your next semester in cash. From here they should be able to tell you the best method for this, though most likely cash/check will suffice. If there is no finance department, or you are still unsure, check with student services for more information.